# Caeser cipher encryption from file in Python

Tags: python, encryption

My Caeser cipher works interactively in the shell with a string, but when I've tried to undertake separate programs to encrypt and decrypt I've run into problems, I don't know whether the input is not being split into a list or not, but the if statement in my encryption function is being bypassed and defaulting to the else statement that fills the list unencrypted. Any suggestions appreciated. I'm using FileUtilities.py from the Goldwasser book. That file is at http://prenhall.com/goldwasser/sourcecode.zip in chapter 11, but I don't think the problem is with that, but who knows. Advance thanks.

```
#CaeserCipher.py
class CaeserCipher:

def __init__ (self, unencrypted="", encrypted=""):
    self._plain = unencrypted
    self._cipher = encrypted
    self._encoded = ""

def encrypt (self, plaintext):
    self._plain = plaintext
    plain_list = list(self._plain)
    i = 0
    final = []

    while (i <= len(plain_list)-1):
        if plain_list[i] in plainset:
            final.append(plainset[plain_list[i]])
        else:
            final.append(plain_list[i])
        i+=1
    self._encoded = ''.join(final)
    return self._encoded

def decrypt (self, ciphertext):
    self._cipher = ciphertext
    cipher_list = list(self._cipher)
    i = 0
    final = []
    while (i <= len(cipher_list)-1):
        if cipher_list[i] in cipherset:
            final.append(cipherset[cipher_list[i]])
        else:
            final.append(cipher_list[i])
        i+=1
    self._encoded = ''.join(final)
    return self._encoded

def writeEncrypted(self, outfile):
    encoded_file = self._encoded
    outfile.write('%s' %(encoded_file))

#encrypt.py
from FileUtilities import openFileReadRobust, openFileWriteRobust
from CaeserCipher import CaeserCipher

caeser = CaeserCipher()

source = openFileReadRobust()
destination = openFileWriteRobust('encrypted.txt')
caeser.encrypt(source)
caeser.writeEncrypted(destination)
source.close()
destination.close()
print 'Encryption completed.'
```

Comment: What is `plainset` (in your `while` condition)?

Answer (score 3):

```
caeser.encrypt(source)
```

into

```
caeser.encrypt(source.read())
```

`source` is a file object - the fact that this code "works" (by not encrypting anything) is interesting - turns out that you call `list()` over the source before iterating and that turns it into a **list of lines in the file**. Instead of the usual result of `list(string)` which is a list of characters. So when it tries to encrypt each chracter, it finds a whole line that doesn't match any of the replacements you set.

Also like others pointed out, you forgot to include plainset in the code, but that doesn't really matter.

A few random notes about your code (probably nitpicking you didn't ask for, heh)

- You typo'd "Caesar"
- You're using idioms which are inefficient in python (what's usually called "not pythonic"), some of which might come from experience with other languages like C.

  - Those while loops could be `for item in string:` - strings already work as lists of bytes like what you tried to convert.
  - The line that writes to outfile could be just `outfile.write(self._encoded)`
- Both functions are very similar, almost copy-pasted code. Try to write a third function that shares the functionality of both but has two "modes", encrypt and decrypt. You could just make it work over cipher_list or plain_list depending on the mode, for example
- I know you're doing this for practice but the standard library includes [these functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm) for this kind of replacements. Batteries included!

**Edit**: if anyone is wondering what those file functions do and why they work, they call `raw_input()` inside a while loop until there's a suitable file to return. `openFileWriteRobust()` has a parameter that is the default value in case the user doesn't input anything. The code is linked on the OP post.

Comment: Thank you, the .read() did the trick. You are great. As for your other suggestions, aside from spelling Caesar correctly, I'm going to stay unpythonic for this project and call it a wrap. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes what's "pythonic" or not is just a matter of taste and minor optimizations. But sometimes it improves code maintainability, particularly when I mentioned to avoid having duplicate code that's too similar. Just take it as a advice for future projects - I can understand that it doesn't really matter for this code. (By the way, remember to accept an answer! I'm fairly new to the website so I'd appreciate it a lot)

Answer (score 1):

Some points:

- Using a context manager (`with`) makes sure that files are closed after being read or written.
- Since the caesar cipher is a substitution cipher where the shift parameter is the key, there is no need for a separate `encrypt` and `decrypt` member function: they are the same but with the "key" negated.
- The `writeEncrypted` method is but a wrapper for a file's write method. So the class has effectively only two methods, one of which is `__init__`.
- That means you could easily replace it with a single function.

With that in mind your code can be replaced with this;

```
import string

def caesartable(txt, shift):
    shift = int(shift)
    if shift > 25 or shift < -25:
        raise ValueError('illegal shift value')
    az = string.ascii_lowercase
    AZ = string.ascii_uppercase
    eaz = az[-shift:]+az[:-shift]
    eAZ = AZ[-shift:]+AZ[:-shift]
    tt = string.maketrans(az + AZ, eaz + eAZ)
    return tt

enc = caesartable(3) # for example. decrypt would be caesartable(-3)
with open('plain.txt') as inf:
    txt = inf.read()
with open('encrypted.txt', 'w+') as outf:
    outf.write(txt.translate(enc))
```

If you are using a shift of 13, you can use the built-in `rot13` encoder instead.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't obvious to me that there will be anything in `source` after the call to `openFileReadRobust()`. I don't know the specification for `openFileReadRobust()` but it seems like it won't know what file to open unless there is a filename given as a parameter, and there isn't one.

Thus, I suspect `source` is empty, thus `plain` is empty too.

I suggest printing out `source`, `plaintext` and `plain` to ensure that their values are what you expect them to be.

Parenthetically, the `openFileReadRobust()` function doesn't seem very helpful to me if it can return non-sensical values for non-sensical parameter values. I very much prefer my functions to throw an exception immediately in that sort of circumstance.

Comment: He did mention that the result is the same as the contents of the input file. Turns out that `source` isn't empty, it's just a file object and this code doesn't throw exceptions by accident. Check my answer.

Comment: You're quite right, the OP did mention this. It puzzled me how anything was being read into the program at all.

Comment: Yeah, I was completely confused too, until I decided to include FileUtilities in the code I was testing instead of changing it to my own open().read()